# Extract unencrypted duplicity backup when all sigtar and most manifest files are missing

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup, duplicity

I am trying to extract a backup from an old duplicity back up (done by the ubuntu gui, I believe it was deja-dup).

I copied all I could off a dying hard drive.  I have

- a lot of `difftar.gz` files - some 2014 and some 2016.
- a single `.manifest` file from 2014.
- no `sigtar.gz` files

The backups are not encrypted - I have unzipped one `difftar.gz` file and examined it in a hex editor and I can see lots of plain text.

Running some commands:

```
% duplicity --no-encryption --ignore-errors collection-status file:///home/hamish/poonbackup2014
Running in 'ignore errors' mode due to --ignore-errors; please re-consider if this was not intended
Last full backup date: Mon Sep 15 19:37:44 2014
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive directory: /home/hamish/.cache/duplicity/c34b5c3ae7d763a715fd062ec5f49baa

Found 1 secondary backup chain.
Secondary chain 1 of 1:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Mon Sep 15 19:37:44 2014
Chain end time: Mon Sep 15 19:37:44 2014
Number of contained backup sets: 1
Total number of contained volumes: 2063
 Type of backup set:                            Time:   Number of volumes:
                Full         Mon Sep 15 19:37:44 2014              2063
-------------------------

No backup chains with active signatures found
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.



% duplicity --no-encryption --ignore-errors collection-status file:///home/hamish/poonbackup2016
Running in 'ignore errors' mode due to --ignore-errors; please re-consider if this was not intended
Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session
Last full backup date: none
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive directory: /home/hamish/.cache/duplicity/37e66337a462669832db8b2b852f9c6f

Found 0 secondary backup chains.
No backup chains with active signatures found
Also found 0 backup sets not part of any chain,
and 2 incomplete backup sets.
These may be deleted by running duplicity with the "cleanup" command.


% duplicity --no-encryption --ignore-errors list-current-files file:///home/hamish/poonbackup2014
Running in 'ignore errors' mode due to --ignore-errors; please re-consider if this was not intended
Synchronising remote metadata to local cache...
Deleting local /home/hamish/.cache/duplicity/f152114ed2326b0ba48e42e6ec0a23d6/duplicity-full.20140915T183744Z.manifest (not authoritative at backend).
Last full backup date: none
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1476, in do_backup
    list_current(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 702, in list_current
    sig_chain = col_stats.get_signature_chain_at_time(time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 998, in get_signature_chain_at_time
    raise CollectionsError("No signature chains found")
 CollectionsError: No signature chains found
```

Assuming I cannot extract any more files from the original hard drive, do I have any options to extract files?

I am most interested in extracting photos - if I could extract a file of photos with no names or file metadata that would be a win at this point.

Comment: Check out the "when everything goes wrong" part of the deja-dup wiki.  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase#Restoring_by_Hand See the Restoring by Hand part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overall followed [the guide in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/417114/629) but I wanted to expand on some points:

### Overall

The `difftar.gz` files are all just plain `tar.gz` files, no encryption.  And if you unpack them all they put their content into a file structure.  The top level has two directories:

- `snapshot/` - this contains plain files, but in my case it had a (very) small subset of the files I cared about - about 100 MB of the 100 GB I wanted to recover.
- `multivol_snapshot/` - this contains a directory for each plain file.  In each directory there are a set of files that have just a number as a filename - `1`, `2`, ...  The filesize appears to always be 64 kB (apart from the last one of course).  You can manually cat the files together, which would work reasonably for a small number of files.  I had a lot though.

### Unpack

First I needed to unpack all the tar gz files:

```bsh
for f in duplicity-full.*.difftar.gz; do echo "$f"; tar xf "$f"; done
```

### Reconstruct

The answer liked above has a shell one liner, but that creates lots of files named `content` mixed in with the original content.  I wanted to recreate the filesystem.  So I wrote the below python script, which takes 2 arguments:

- a directory inside `multivol_snapshot/` containing the bits you want to restore
- a directory to put the restored files inside.

It will recursively go through everything and recreate the files.  Provided you have all the chunks required, it will work fine ...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import sys


class FileReconstructor():

    def __init__(self, unpacked_dir, restore_dir):
        self.unpacked_path = Path(unpacked_dir).resolve()
        self.restore_path = Path(restore_dir).resolve()

    def reconstruct_files(self):
        for leaf_dir in self.walk_unpacked_leaf_dirs():
            target_path = self.target_path(leaf_dir)
            target_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            with target_path.open('wb') as target_file:
                self.copy_file_parts_to(target_file, leaf_dir)

    def copy_file_parts_to(self, target_file, leaf_dir):
        file_parts = sorted(leaf_dir.iterdir(), key=lambda x: int(x.name))
        for file_part in file_parts:
            with file_part.open('rb') as source_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(source_file, target_file)

    def walk_unpacked_leaf_dirs(self):
        """
        based on the assumption that all leaf files are named as numbers
        """
        seen_dirs = set()
        for path in self.unpacked_path.rglob('*'):
            if path.is_file():
                if path.parent not in seen_dirs:
                    seen_dirs.add(path.parent)
                    yield path.parent

    def target_path(self, leaf_dir_path):
        return self.restore_path / leaf_dir_path.relative_to(self.unpacked_path)


def parse_args(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'unpacked_dir',
        help='The directory with the unpacked tar files',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'restore_dir',
        help='The directory to restore files into',
    )
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


def main(argv):
    args = parse_args(argv)
    reconstuctor = FileReconstructor(args.unpacked_dir, args.restore_dir)
    return reconstuctor.reconstruct_files()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

collection status finds a chain in file:///home/hamish/poonbackup2014 . so theoretically you should be able to restore the **whole** backup.
signatures are only needed to restore single files/folders or list the contents.

..ede/duply.net